# Devise - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I made a custom layout for my not-logged-in users. When I open it however it says `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. I've done some googling and it seems it has something to do with not having the code in the controller properly. (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2451)

I don't use a custom controller for Devise and don't feel like doing so if its not neccesary.

Is there a way to bypass this error without using a custom controller?

The error is created on the `form_for` of new(resource)

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name,
    :url => session_path(resource_name) ,
    :html => {:id => "sign_in_user"},
    #:format => :json,
    :remote => true, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's saying `resource` has no data?

---

**Devise**

Since you're using `resource`, I'd imagine you're referring to Devise's ability to [load forms on multiple pages](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app):

```
  #app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Maybe this will help?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you init resource in your custom controller as **self.resource**

e.g.

```
self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
```

Comment: You should highlight that SELF is the important part. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem and ensure that `resource` wasn't nil in a Rails 4.2 app, I needed to add `build_resource({})` to my registrations#new action.  I was inheriting from the Devise::Registrations controller, but not relying on `super`.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L99

No error was being thrown prior to upgrading to Rails 4.2 from Rails 3.2

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the case for me. Btw, you can just use build_resource , without the empty hash argument